# SonarQube Eclipse doesn't show me issues after a local analysis

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner

Using SonarQube Eclipse plugin, I run remote analysis [Sonar > Mode > Remote] (localhost:9000 and ip_on_my_lan:9000) and I see Sonar Issues tab with some elements (everything is OK).

But if I run local analysis I don't have any issue on Sonar Issues tab and Eclipse deletes all issues marks from source code. 
It seems sonar-runner local analysis was OK:  INFO  - ANALYSIS SUCCESSFUL

What I'm doing wrong?

I tried with:

- Eclipse Kepler, Sonar 3.7, SonarQube Plugin 3.0 and 3.2
- Eclipse Juno, Sonar 3.7, SonarQube Plugin  3.0 and 3.2

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Do you see anything special in Eclipse logs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem!!!!

I have my sources on src/test/java instead of src/main/java  (test framework)

If I run my analysis with "sonar-runner.bat" everything is ok, but when I run a local analysis from eclipse it seems eclipse doesn't found any source, but it doesn't say anything...

Eclipse put the binary code on /target/test-classes/  and I think Sonar plugin can't found it.

So I have two options: Move my source to src/main/java (checked) or create new local analysis properties (sonar.binaries)

Thanks for your time!